# Django Rest Framework custom error messages

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add custom field error messages for SlugRelated field as follows:

```
class Test(serializers.ModelSerializers):
    team = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), slug_field='name',
                                        error_messages={"does_not_exist": "Team not found"})
```

Works as expected. My query is how do I pass the team name dynamically in the error message. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
class Test(serializers.ModelSerializers):
    team = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Team.objects.all(), slug_field='name',
                                        error_messages={"does_not_exist": f"Team {team} not found"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default error message for `does_not_exist` take `slug_name` & `value` as the keyword argument to format the error string.

Solution is to replace `team` with `value`.

**Solution**:

```
class Test(serializers.ModelSerializers):
    team = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Team.objects.all(),
        slug_field='name',
        error_messages={"does_not_exist": "Team {value} not found"}
    )
```

Ref: [relations:SlugRelatedField Source Code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L462)

Comment: Right. Forgot to convert it back to regular string from f-string. Updating the answer.